# Java: why do we get Matcher from Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Why did java developers did the way we get matcher from pattern? I mean why

```
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(string)
```

I think logically there must be something like

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher=new Matcher(pattern,string);
//if we need
matcher.setPattern(newPattern);
```

I mean a matcher is like an regex engine and pattern is like commands for this engine. Why do we create engine from commands?

Comment: `matcher.usePattern(newPattern);` changes the pattern to a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of the pattern matching algorithm needs to keep track of certain state variables.

Since `Pattern` represents a threadsafe object it cannot itself contain these variables (else it would not be threadsafe), therefore these variables are stored in a matcher object which is created for a single match call and which is not threadsafe. From the `Pattern` Javadoc:

> Instances of this class are immutable and are safe for use by multiple
>   concurrent threads. Instances of the Matcher class are not safe for
>   such use.

Additionally the `Matcher` class also provides access to match results like match groups etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) Javadoc,

> A matcher is created from a pattern by invoking the pattern's [`matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.

This is an example of a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Per the linked Wikipedia page

> the intention of the builder pattern is to find a solution to the telescoping constructor [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

Comment: I don't think it's Builder pattern. The Pattern contains the algorithm to do matching, which is static. The Matcher contains the match state, which is variable. The setPattern method is for changing the matching algorithm in the middle of a match. I can't see how it's an example of Builder pattern, where you constructs an object by setting different methods, and the object becomes concrete after it's built.